# Is there a way to click a <span> tag by span content

Tags: java, selenium

I have a dropdown box that is comprised of span tags with no id/class/name etc.

```
<span data-hj-masked="">Friday 5:30</span>
<span data-hj-masked="">Saturday 3:30</span>
<span data-hj-masked="">Monday 1:30</span>
```

Is there a way to click by text only in Selenium?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("span[contains(text(),'Friday 5:30']")).click();
```

Should be able to click Friday 5:30.

Answer (score 4):

You did some small mistake: before the last `]` sign should be `)` sign :)
The right XPath is:

```
//span[contains(text(),'Friday 5:30')]
```

Also, you can use the following XPaths:

```
//span[text()='Friday 5:30']
//span[.='Friday 5:30']
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Since you are comparing the full textContent of the element, you can remove the `contains()` reference, e.g. `//span[.='Friday 5:30']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, so you can use same method for any span in this selection:

```
public void selectSpanByText(final String text) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='" + text + "']")).click();
}
```